# Using $http angular service to make post request in coffeescript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I am trying to write a post request alongwith handling on error or success in coffeescript in a angularjs controller but not able to do so. Following is what I have tried:

```
requestData = {url:"www.example.com/Tags", data:pageTags, method:"post"}
request = $http requestData
request.error = (data) ->
                  alert("failed")
request.success = (data) ->
                  alert("success")
```

I can see a network request being made, but the error and success alerts are not seen

Comment: You don't assign values to `error` and `success`, those are methods. In regular JS it would be `request.success(function(data) { ... })` (I don't do CoffeeScript)

Comment: I am looking for coffeescript help here. I know I am doing wrong, but not able to figure out

Comment: Thanks Phil for your comment though, I solved this for me working in that direction :)

Answer (score 1):

Coffee script for you code, try this,

```
$http.post(
  url: 'www.example.com/Tags'
  data: pageTags).success((data) ->
  alert 'success'
  return
).error (data) ->
  alert 'failed'
  return
```